# A question about Bézout coefficients

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations

Let’s say that $p,q,r$ are positive integers, with $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $r=kp+mq$ being the Bézout representation. When $(k,m)$ are “minimal”, we know that $\lvert{m}\rvert < \lvert{p}\rvert$.

Now let’s say that [by other means] I’ve proven that $p \mid (m^2-2)$. Is there a way that I can guarantee the size of the quotient? *e.g.,* can I ever say “For one of the two minimal values of $m$, we must have $m^2-2=p$”? If that’s not always guaranteed, what are the ways I can go about finding a concrete quotient for $\tfrac{m^2-2}{p}$?

EDIT: Regarding the “by other means” comment… One relationship between the three variables is
$$r^2=p^2+2pq+2q^2\!.$$
Substituting $r=kp+mq$ into that gives $p \mid (m^2-2)$ and $q \mid (k^2-1)$. Based on other relationships I know to be true of the numbers involved, I know that $p=7$ and $-3,4$ are the two minimal coefficients, so $m^2-2 = (-3)^2-2 = 7 = 1(7)$ and $m^2-2 = (4)^2-2 = 14 = 2(7)$ give $1$ and $2$ as the two related quotients.

Comment: Could you mind explaining how you found $p|m^2-2$. Is this result from a particular problem you were solving that is related to bezout's lemma, or do you think this is a general result? Actually, I don't think it is a general result. For example if $(p,q,r)=(2,3,7)$. Then the minimal value of $m$ is $1,-1$

Comment: @AlanAbraham: These particular numbers $p,q,r$ are elements in a Diophantine equation I’m working on. Setting $r=kp+mq$ and putting that into various relations I have between $p,q,r$ yielded $p \mid (m^2-2)$ and $q \mid (k^2-1)$.

Comment: Bézout representation of what? Of $r$ ?  I agree with @AlanAbraham , that we need more of your motivating problem before us to be able to suggest any attack to you.

Answer (score 0):

Comment:

An experimental approach:

We can see that if (p, q)=1 and p, q and r are constant then there is only one linear relation between them. I show this with some examples:

$(r, p, q)=(452, 31, 47)\rightarrow (k=7)\times 31+(m=5)\times 47 =452$

$(r, p, q)=(2034, 35, 67)\rightarrow (k=16)\times 35+(m=22)\times 67=2034$

But if $(p, q)\neq1$ or p and q have a coommon factor greater than 1, then the linear relation is not unique, for example:

$(p, q, r)=(1990, 35, 65)\rightarrow (k, m)=(3,29), (16, 22), (29, 15)$

In this case better question is: when ($k+m$) is minimum. In this example $3+29=32$ is minimum.